# Why should method calls to .NET components not be made within event handlers subscribed to that same component?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I'm looking into an audio component - AudioSoundRecorder for .NET - and on [one of their documentation pages](http://www.multimediasoft.com/asrecnet/help/index.html?how_to_synchronize_the_contain.htm), they state:

> A call to a method of a certain .NET component should be never performed from within a management function of an event generated by the same .NET component: this is usually cause of errors and dead-lock situations and it's a practice that should be always avoided...

I've never heard of this limitation of .NET before. Can anybody explain to me why this should always be avoided, beyond the 'errors and dead-lock situations' mentioned? Surely handling deadlocks should be the responsibility of the component?

Comment: A rather sweeping statement, I agree. However, I can imagine scenarios where calling a component from its event handler could cause infinite recursion to occur.

Comment: That limitation is unheard of to me, too; after all, the [`EventHandler` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that should be used as a basic type for all events comes with a `sender` parameter whose entire point is allowing calls to the instance that fired the event. I suspect that either they are referring to a rather specific situation with obscure terminology (neither "management function" nor ".NET component" nor "generate an event" are common ways to express things in C#) or that library is for some reason very fragile.

Answer (score 0):

> Surely handling deadlocks should be the responsibility of the component?

Theoretically, for well-behaved components, yes. But some components may not do that.
Also, since this is part of the internal structure of a component, it may change between versions e.g. if version 1 unintentionally prevented deadlocks, but after architectural changes v2 does not prevent them any more. In that case, updating a dependency could break your code.

Thus it's best not to call component methods in a handler for one of the component's events, or, if you must do so, handle deadlocks yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of the AudioSoundRecorder, I reckon what theyt mean is something along the lines of this:

An Event is a simple asynchronous method call. If an event is raised by a component calling a method in external (to the component) code, and that external code calls back into the component, you have a situation where:

1. the component is in the middle of doing something which has not yet finished
2. The component calls external code via an event
3. The external code calls back into the component to do something else

At this point, you have the possibility that as the component hasn't actually finished step 1, whatever it's been asked to do in step 3 may or may not be appropriate. For example, is step 1 is to load a large sound file, the event in step 2 is to say "I'm x% through the load", and the request made to the component is to analyse the sound file, that analyse request will probably fail as the file is not completely loaded.

Note that while the event code is running, the component code isn't: the event call is usually asynchronous, so that the component probably can't do any processing until the event call returns (when the called method is finished). The more you do in the called method, the slower the component will be to finish the original call in step 1.

Also note that in the example I have detailed above, if step 3 calls Analyse when the percentage loaded is 100, the original Load call still hasn't returned: it won't actually return until the event is processed and control returns to the component whereupon it can finish up and retrun to the calling code (whatever called step 1).

Does that help?

Comment: The methods subscribed to an event do not have to be called asynchronously.

Comment: Indeed not, but unless you know the implementation of the component raising the event it's not a good idea to rely on that.